# How can i upload an image which is created by imagecreatefromjpeg to the server?

Tags: php

I am creating a new image from an image which is already uploaded to server. I want to upload the new image to another folder in my server.. I create the image with the code below, how can i upload $jpg_image to the folder?

```
    <?php
    $myu="a";   
    $time = time();
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $hour= date("H");
    $minute =date("i");
    $day = date("d");
    $month = date("m");
    $year = date("Y");
    $mysex =$_SESSION['se'];
    $cappic = $_POST['cappic'];
    $usttxt = $_POST['ust'];
    $alttxt = $_POST['alt'];
    $altfont = $_POST['altfont'];
    $ustfont = $_POST['ustfont'];


    // Create Image From Existing File
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize("image.jpg");

    // Allocate A Color For The Text
    $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
    $color2 = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 0, 0);

    // Set Path to Font File
    $font_path = 'impact.ttf';

    // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
    $text = $usttxt;
    $fs = $ustfont;
    $dimensions = imagettfbbox($fs, 0, $font_path, $text);
    $loc1 = $width-$dimensions[2];
    $loc1 = $loc1/2;
    $bot= $fs+10;


    // Print Text On Image
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc1, $bot+2, $color2, $font_path, $text);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc1, $bot-2, $color2, $font_path, $text);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc1-2, $bot, $color2, $font_path, $text);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc1+2, $bot, $color2, $font_path, $text);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc1, $bot, $white, $font_path, $text);


    $text2 = $alttxt;
    $fs = $altfont;
    $dimensions2 = imagettfbbox($fs, 0, $font_path, $text2);
    $loc2 = $width-$dimensions2[2];
    $loc2 = $loc2/2;
    $bot=$height-20;

    // Print Text On Image
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc2, $bot+2, $color2, $font_path, $text2);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc2, $bot-2, $color2, $font_path, $text2);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc2-2, $bot, $color2, $font_path, $text2);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc2+2, $bot, $color2, $font_path, $text2);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, $fs, 0, $loc2, $bot, $white, $font_path, $text2);

    // Send Image to Browser
    imagejpeg($jpg_image);
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);

    // Clear Memory
    ?>
```

Comment: [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) ?

Comment: i tried copy($jpg_image,"/upload_folder/aaa.jpg") but it did not work. maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: You should put the image original _filename_, not the resource.

Comment: I want to upload $jpg_image to a folder, but you say i need to write the original file.. So should i write copy("image.jpg","/upload_folder/aaa.jpg") to save $jpg_image which is newly created?

Comment: but your image is already on the server, isn't? So there's no uploading, you just need to copy it (then remove the original). You need to supply a filename like this `copy("orig.jpg","somewhere/copied.jpg")`. You cannot use `$jpg_image` as this is not a filename, is a resource and resources cannot be moved around in disk.

Comment: there is something weird.. i tested copy in a new php file like copy("http://www.example.com/caps/org/0001.jpg", "http://www.example.com/ul/copied.jpg"); but it did not work either.. Do we need to set some kind of permision for copy?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `file_put_contents()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Ex.)

```
file_put_contents('folder/folder_2/' . $filename, $file);
```

Comment: file_put_contents('/ul/' . $jpg_image, "aaa.jpg"); i tried this but did not work..

Comment: yah that should work, assuming `aaa.jpg` is the file you want to upload and `$jpg_image` is the name of the file you want it to be saved as.

Comment: i tried this.. file_put_contents('/ul/aaaa.jpg', $jpg_image); because $jpg_image is created with imagecreatefromjpeg, it did not work for me..

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are you sure the file directory is correct?

Comment: I dont get any errors, i used this to be sure about the directory file_put_contents('http://www.example.com/ul/aaaa.jpg', $jpg_image); but still did not work.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, setting a path in imagejpeg() solves it.. Thanks for all answers.